# ngx-bootstrap proper way for pagination

Tags: angular

I decided to switch from ng-bootstrap to ngx-bootstrap because it has animations and it's more complete. I was looking at *Content switching* example in their [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/pagination#content-switching) but it requires an additional variable which later causes more issues because my loading in `bots.component.ts` relies on `@Input() bots: BotListView[];` variable. Complete code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkdzen

Apparently, the way I did it with slice, is not recommended. By the way, the code below is same as the one from StackBlitz.

[image]

I'm simply looking for a proper way to do that since slice is not recommended. *Content switching* example looks good to me but as I've explained above, I can't use it because I have to change my loading bar logic. How are you guys doing it?

bots-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { BotListView } from 'src/app/core/types/bot';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bots-list',
  templateUrl: './bots-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bots-list.component.css']
})
export class BotsListComponent {
  @Input() bots: BotListView[];
  @Output() deleted = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<number>();

  page = 1;
  pageSize = 2;

  deleteBot(id: number) {
    this.deleted.emit(id);
  }

  editBot(id: number) {
    this.selected.emit(id);
  }
}
```

bots-list.component.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover text-center mt-4">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">ID</th>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Status</th>
        <th class="text-center">Symbol</th>
        <th class="text-center">Interval</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr
        *ngFor="let bot of bots | reverse | slice: (page - 1) * pageSize:(page - 1) * pageSize + pageSize; trackBy: bot?.id">
        <td class="align-middle">{{ bot.id }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ bot.name }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ bot.status }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ bot.cryptoPair.description }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ bot.timeInterval.description }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="editBot(bot.id)">Edit</button> &nbsp;
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="deleteBot(bot.id)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<pagination [boundaryLinks]="true" [totalItems]="bots?.length" [(ngModel)]="page" [itemsPerPage]="pageSize">
</pagination>
```